# Search On "and - Or" in SQL contains

Tags: sql-server

I want to use put (and - Or ) inside the SQL contains query

let we consider that we have a field BOOK_Title contain data for example: "C# AND C++"

computed_column: `BOOK_Title +' '+Book_Auther`
 I use:

```
select *
from VW_Items 
where contains(computed_column, 'C# and and and C++')
```

and also I use:

```
select *
from VW_Items 
where contains(computed_column, 'C# and C++')
```

Comment: I don't understand your statement here, can you try to explain further. What is your question as well? You only state what you want. Perhaps include some sample data and your expected results *P.s. it's spelt Author. ;)*

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to only have two, I don't see a need for an AND if you want an OR.  The OR would grab either term, the AND only those that contain both.  Unless I misunderstand your question then the desired AND/OR would ideally grab either term just like the OR.

If you want to distinguish the two I'd go for something similar to this, though there may be more optimal ways to "weight" the results:

```
select CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('C#', computed_column) > 0 AND CHARINDEX('C++', computed_column) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Relevance, *
from VW_Items 
where contains(computed_column, 'C# and C++')
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```